# Why are clicks not corresponding correctly to XY positions?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to make custom buttons in LibGDX (I really only wanted to use it for the Android/Desktop portability, not for any of its features, like Scene2D)

The issue I'm having is that the clickable area and the texture don't have a 100% overlap. I can click some places in the texture that don't respond to my isClicked method, and there are places outside the texture that do. I just don't understand what's happening.

Here's my button  class.

```
public class btn
{
private Texture btnTexture;

private int x;
private int y;

private int width;
private int height;


public btn(String btnTexturePathSet, int xSet , int ySet)
{
    btnTexture = new Texture(btnTexturePathSet);
    x = xSet;
    y = ySet;
    width = btnTexture.getWidth();
    height = btnTexture.getHeight();

}

public void render(SpriteBatch sb)
{
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(btnTexture, x, y);
    sb.end();
}

public boolean isClicked()
{
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched())
    {
        if (Gdx.input.getY() >= y && Gdx.input.getY() <= y + height && Gdx.input.getX() >= x && Gdx.input.getX() <= x + width)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: I must ask - why not use Scene2D for this since it already has support for all the strange cross-platform behavior? If you're looking for cross-platform Scene2D will save you a lot of work. As for the question itself: Are you using a camera / viewport?

Comment: @Charanor I'm not using Scene2D because I am creating a simple turn based text game, and felt that learning and implementing the features of LibGDX was unnecessary for this style of game. It is literally 100% buttons, text outputs, and screen changes. I felt this way because Scene2D seemed like more coding than was necessary for something so simple. AlsoIt took me five days of continuously new errors to get Android Studio installed

Yes, I am using a camera, orthographic, but no, I have yet to implement viewports. I was using a barebones gamestatemanager than relied on Java's Stack function.

Comment: It appears, though, that I'm not going to be able to create this simple game with this library without implementing its features. Where can I learn the basics of Scene2D, with the barebones, minimum code for buttons and state changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. First, make sure your orthographic camera is set to false for yDown

then, make sure to use camera.unproject() after gathering the input x,y's, but before applying them;

```
        mouse.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        cam.unproject(mouse);

        if (mouse.y <= y + height  && mouse.y >= y && mouse.x >= x && mouse.x <= x + width)
        {
            return true;
        }
```